# Adobe AIR and different OS filesystems

Tags: actionscript-3, filesystems, operating-system, air

Another Adobe Air question for you but first here some background into the project I have been tasked with.  It is an AIR app that will read assets from a USB key and must work on both WIN and MacOS.  The problem is, how do I load assets into the app on MacOS!  Sounds simple enough and works seamlessly on Windows.

Here is a code snippet of what i am trying to do:

```
            var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ok);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);

            var p:String;

            if (os == "mac")
            {
                p = "/Volumes/" + keyVolume.rootDirectory.name + File.separator + "0a0ff0ff-f7ae-4b9c-9637-843b1d6c80e8.jpg";
            }
            else
            {
                p = keyVolume.rootDirectory.name + File.separator + "0a0ff0ff-f7ae-4b9c-9637-843b1d6c80e8.jpg";
            }

            var temp:File = new File(p);
            Debugger.Display.text += "\nAttempting to load: " + p;
            Debugger.Display.text += "\nDoes it exist? " + temp.exists;
            loader.load(new URLRequest(p));
```

... the variable OS and keyVolume are being successfully set in earlier code.  Also, I have the event listener callbacks defined as well for ok() and ioErro().

When this is run it prints out on windows:

Attempting to load: G:\0a0ff0ff-f7ae-4b9c-9637-843b1d6c80e8.jpg
Does it exist: true

... and then successfully loads the asset.

On MacOS, it prints out:

Attempting to load: /Volumes/AC/0a0ff0ff-f7ae-4b9c-9637-843b1d6c80e8.jpg
Does it exist: true

... and then fails with an IOError every time.

Can anyone see something that I am missing here?  Do I have some sort of permission error or something (file has "read / write" access).  The USB key is formatted in MS-DOS FAT32, could that be a problem?

**EDIT**

I formatted a new USB key in MacOS to FAT16 and put the files onto it with no success.  Problems remain.

**EDIT**

I am now just trying to load an asset from /users/-USERNAME-/Desktop and still am receiving the same error, so it looks like it isn't a permissions issue on just the USB stick, it is more widespread than that.

**EDIT**

PROBLEM SOLVED!  I finally worded my Google search correctly and it [revealed the answer](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/701762?tstart=0).

These changes will fix the problem:

```
            var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ok);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);

            var p:String = keyVolume.rootDirectory.nativePath + ((os == "mac") ? File.separator : "") + "0a0ff0ff-f7ae-4b9c-9637-843b1d6c80e8.jpg";
            var temp:File = new File(p);
            Debugger.Display.text += "\nAttempting to load: " + temp.url;
            Debugger.Display.text += "\nDoes it exist? " + temp.exists;
            loader.load(new URLRequest(temp.url));
```

I have also refined the logical statement involving the OS detection a bit as well.

I hope someone finds this useful!

Comment: FAT32 should be totally fine. Do you have more info on the IOError?

Comment: What's the "AC" difference in the paths ?

Comment: The "AC" in MacOS is the drive name.  It does not factor into the windows path as it uses drive letters.

Comment: Using the url property instead of the nativePath property of the File class fixed a mac issue I was having! Thanks for posting what you found!

Comment: Samuel, thanks for the advise.  Mudasir has tried to hijack the answer already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED!  I finally worded my Google search correctly and it [revealed the answer](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/701762?tstart=0).

These changes will fix the problem:

```
            var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ok);
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, ioError);

            var p:String = keyVolume.rootDirectory.nativePath + ((os == "mac") ? File.separator : "") + "0a0ff0ff-f7ae-4b9c-9637-843b1d6c80e8.jpg";
            var temp:File = new File(p);
            Debugger.Display.text += "\nAttempting to load: " + temp.url;
            Debugger.Display.text += "\nDoes it exist? " + temp.exists;
            loader.load(new URLRequest(temp.url));
```

I have also refined the logical statement involving the OS detection a bit as well.

I hope someone finds this useful!